# Prove that $P(A \cap B) \leq P(A) + P(B)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I need to use theorem 2.7 which says that : $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

I started by solving the above equation for $P(A \cap B)$.

I got: $P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)$.

Is that enough to say that $P(A \cap B) \leq P(A) + P(B)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Since probabilities are nonnegative, we know that $P(A \cup B) \geq 0$ so that $-P(A \cup B) \leq 0$. Hence:
$$
P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) \leq P(A) + P(B) + 0 = P(A) + P(B)
$$
as desired.

Comment: If they *need* to use this theorem, then this is good. However, when I first saw the question, I thought as [Kim Jong Un](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/918758) did.

Comment: @robjohn Agreed. My only concern is that I'm not sure if it's obvious that $X \subseteq Y \implies P(X) \leq P(Y)$.

Comment: @Adriano If $X\subseteq Y$ then if $X$ happens then $Y$ must also happen, but it *may* be possible for $Y$ to happen without $X$ happening. The probability of $Y$ happening must be *at least* as great as the probability of $X$ happening. $Y \equiv X \cap Y\backslash X \implies \mathsf P (Y) = \mathsf P (X) + \mathsf P (Y\backslash X)$

Answer (score 5):

$$
A\cap B\subset A\implies P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)=P(A)+0\leq P(A)+P(B).
$$